# How to get the index of the smallest element in a vector?

Tags: c++, vector

I want to know which element of vector is the minimum, but `min_element` returns an iterator to the element. So I tried this:

```
vector<int> vec = {4,5,0,1,2,3} ;
int min_element_index = min_element(vec.begin(), vec.end()) - vec.begin();
```

However, I'm unsure this will always work. I don't know how vectors are stored in memory, and I'm worried this will break when I use `push_back`.

Comment: I'm not sure it will always work .Are vector elements stored continuously ?

Comment: Vector elements are stored continuously in memory. But you don't need to care unless you use `vector::data` which most of the time you shouldn't do anyway.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can also do this:

```
std::vector<int>::iterator it = std::min_element(std::begin(vec), std::end(vec));
std::cout << "index of smallest element: " << std::distance(std::begin(vec), it);
```

or even simpler:

```
auto it = std::min_element(std::begin(vec), std::end(vec));
std::cout << "index of smallest element: " << std::distance(std::begin(vec), it);
```

or:

```
std::cout << "index of smallest element: " <<
std::distance(std::begin(v), std::min_element(std::begin(v), std::end(v)))
```

Comment: I like this answer the most since it is more generic and will work with non random access containers as well.

Answer (score 3):

Vector members are guaranteed to be stored in contiguous memory, which doesn't really matter here.

The vector iterators are random access iterators, so subtracting vector iterators is well defined (This will always work with a standards compliant `std::vector`)

To convert a vector iterator into a pointer, you can do `&*(vector-iterator)`, but there is no reason to here.